# VBA looping through open word documents?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm trying to loop through all of the word documents that I currently have open, check the filename and pass the document to a function if the document name matches certain criteria. This is the code I currently have:

```
Dim doc As word.Document

For Each doc In word.Documents
    If doc.Name Like "*scratchpad*" Then
        Call ModifyScratchpad(doc)
    End If
Next
```

This seems to work well some of the time but if I close the docs and reopen them, then run the sub again, I'll get an error at line 2:

```
"The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable."
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong to loop through open Word docs but not sure what.

Does anyone have an idea of how to loop through all open Word docs and avoid this error?

Comment: The message indicates an OLE problem. It looks like you're running this from Access, so that program is losing touch with the Word instance. After closing the Word docs and reopening, you'll have to reestablish the connection from Access.

Comment: If you're running this from access it would help to show how you get your reference to Word in the first place, before you start looping.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean reestablish the connection from Access? That's actually all the code I was using, so I'm clearly missing something. Apologies for missing something - I'm new to Word VBA!

Comment: I have no idea why closing and then opening documents would make a difference. Have you tried the statement: Option Compare Text?